# How can I 'layer' a keybinding?

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

I'm trying to create an [emmet-like](https://github.com/smihica/emmet-mode) minor mode that will trigger on `SPC` (or `TAB`) if the previous text is expandable, but I don't want to completely override bindings that already exist for the key.

How can I 'layer' my functionality over existing configuration?

```
(if (should-activate-p)
    (do-the-cool-thing)
  (business-as-usual))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various ways you could approach this, but one in particular seems more or less designed for the purpose.

You define the key using the `menu-item` syntax, with a `:filter` function that *returns the command to be called.* If the function returns `nil`, Emacs treats it as undefined in that keymap, and continues looking for a binding in the lower-priority maps.

Some examples are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090517/elisp-conditionally-change-keybinding/22863701#22863701
- http://endlessparentheses.com/define-context-aware-keys-in-emacs.html
- http://paste.lisp.org/display/304865