# How do I run a function upon pressing a prefix key?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

Trivial example of what I would like to do:

```
(define-prefix-command 'my-prefix-map)

(defun populate-my-prefix ()
  (define-key my-prefix-map (kbd "a") #'move-beginning-of-line))

(define-key global-map (kbd "<f6>") #'my-prefix-map)
```

Upon pressing `f6` I would like to run `populate-my-prefix`, before `my-prefix-map` is executed.

I think Hydra can do something like this (call another function upon entering the Hydra), but I'm writing my own package and would rather not depend on it.

Comment: does it work if you just bind `populate-my-prefix` to f6, but have it return the keymap?

Comment: @XahLee Not sure, I somewhat solved it by binding it to `poulate-my-prefix` and at the end of that function I used `(set-transient-map 'my-prefix-map)`. That works, but I feel that it doesn't really answer the actual question. I also tried using `add-advice` and `add-function` to `my-prefix-map`, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question, but I don't have time to look for it now...

Comment: Perhaps you can use a 'conditional key binding' such that it does something the first time and sets some state so that the condition no longer applies on subsequent calls? See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26295/how-can-i-layer-a-keybinding/26297#26297.